# Python datetime parsing timestamp with timezone

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timestamp, timezone

I ran into this problem a while back ago where parsing an ISO string with time zone data and parsing a timestamp (supposedly of the same time) will give different results. I have written a test to check this behavior and it seems pretty inconsistent:

```
from pytz import timezone as tz
from datetime import datetime

timezone = "Australia/Sydney"
start_time = "2021-05-04T08:12:00"
tz_object = tz(timezone)
naive_datetime = datetime.fromisoformat(start_time)


zoned_time = datetime(naive_datetime.year, naive_datetime.month, naive_datetime.day, naive_datetime.hour, naive_datetime.minute, naive_datetime.second, tzinfo=tz_object)
parsed_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(zoned_time.timestamp(), tz_object)

assert zoned_time.time() == naive_datetime.time()
assert zoned_time.time() == parsed_time.time()
```

This test produces the following output

```
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    assert zoned_time.time() == parsed_time.time()
  AssertionError
```

Unless I'm missing something I can only conclude that the time resulting from this line

```
parsed_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(zoned_time.timestamp(), tz_object)
```

Is producing a different time than parsing the actual ISO string. Typically I'd expect the timestamp from the parsed time return a timestamp referring to 8:12 am in the time zone it was assigned.

Is this behavior expected?
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Python 3.9, use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). Note that there is a deprecation shim for [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/) if required.

Your code then works fine like

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

timezone = "Australia/Sydney"
tz_object = ZoneInfo(timezone)

start_time = "2021-05-04T08:12:00"
naive_datetime = datetime.fromisoformat(start_time)

zoned_time = datetime(naive_datetime.year, naive_datetime.month, naive_datetime.day, naive_datetime.hour, naive_datetime.minute, naive_datetime.second, tzinfo=tz_object)
parsed_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(zoned_time.timestamp(), tz_object)

assert zoned_time.time() == naive_datetime.time()
assert zoned_time.time() == parsed_time.time()
```

As to *why* you got an assertion error: with `pytz` you need to `localize` the datetime object with the time zone; **never set a tzinfo directly with pytz**.